# How to make Android CircleImageView in middle of layout

Tags: java, android, view

I don't know how to describe this but I have attached image for your reference[image: circular view]

Question is how do you create this one? Or any libraries you can recommend. Thanks!

NOTE: I know CircularImageView. What I'm asking is the ImageView inside that layout

Comment: See this link https://gist.github.com/cesco89/9144189

Comment: https://github.com/hangox/CircleImageView

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya hi pls. check my updated post

Comment: the part where it's half in the layout is probably an effet of margins on the light green background

Comment: @njzk2 can you suggest or give links to any tutorials? So i can follow. thanks

Answer (score 1):

For this I will recommend to use [this](https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView) library. I used this one and it is really easy to implement and easy to use according to my circumstances it really worked well . I suggest you to use this. Well there are many other also. But this one really work nice .

If you need some help feel free to ask. And if this library is good to you , then please vote up and pick it as a right answer.

Comment: Yes I know CircularImageView, I'm referring to the view and the layout

Comment: circularview inside the layout but you see it's extending past the layout

Comment: @bEtTyBarnes using CircularImageView library you will have to adjust it using margin and padding... and design the layout accordingly

Comment: this library can be used in layout easily you can use it as you want and where you want

Comment: @stacyqueen hi I've updated my question. sorry for confusion. I know CircleImageView. What I want to do is position the view in middle of layout.

Answer (score 0):

I've used this library in one of my projects [CircleImageView](https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can take al look at [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/). This is a very good library and also has the possibility to make an image round.

Comment: I mean the circular imageview half in the layout

Comment: please make sure you elaborate more on what your question is. referring to an image and then saying "What I'm asking is the ImageView inside that layout" doesn't make it clear for me.

Comment: Put your circleimage and the rest of the light green layout in a relativelayout. If you know the height of the circleimage. Set the padding or margin in the top to half of the height. This causes the layout, with everything but the inageview, to shift down. So a relative layout with a imaview and a linearlayout for the rest.